# SQL conversion failed when converting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

following situation:

a column xy is defined as varchar(25). In a view (SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2008) I filtered all values with letters (-> is not like '%[A-Z]%') and converted it to int (cast(xy as int)).

If I now try to make comprisons with that column (e.g. where xy < 1000), I'm getting a conversion error. And the message contains a value that should have been filtered with "is not like '%[A-Z]%'". Whats wrong??

thanks for help in advance...

this works (it folters out for example value 'G8111'):
SELECT     unid
FROM       CD_UNITS AS a INNER JOIN DEF_STATION AS b ON a.STATION = b.STATION
WHERE      (b.CURENT = 'T') and UNID   like '%[A-Z]%'

but when i put that in a view, an make select on it:

select * from my_view where xy < 3000

system says 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'G8111' to data type int.' but 'G8111' should be filtered out in query above...

Comment: Your filter is only for letters; are there other characters in your data (like commas or other punctuation) that won't cast to int? Plus, your filter is upper-case; is the value that should have been filtered lower-case?

Comment: it would be more readable, you if would edit your question with the query for view generation itself

Comment: You might want to read and vote on [SQL Server should not produce illogical errors](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Comment: sorry - deleted prev comment, wasn't thinking. the better filter would be WHERE ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 Then you guarantee its numeric at least (although could be outside the range of an int still)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC(value)=1` is a pointless check because, as you say, values that cannot be converted to `int` will be accepted, including such gems as `£` by itself and `0d0`.

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer does [crazy things](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) at times, so despite the fact that an "inner" filter<sup>1</sup> "should" protect you, the optimizer may still push the conversion lower down than the filter and cause such errors.

The only semi-documented place where it will not do this is within a [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> The CASE statement(*sic*) evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. In some situations, an expression is evaluated before a CASE statement receives the results of the expression as its input.
>
> ...
>
> You should only depend on order of evaluation of the WHEN conditions for scalar expressions (including non-correlated sub-queries that return scalars), not for aggregate expressions

So the only way that should currently work would be:

```
CASE WHEN xy NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,xy) END < 1000
```

This also uses a double-negative with `LIKE` to ensure that it only attempts the conversion when the value only contains digits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether this be in a subquery, a CTE, a View, or even just considering the [logical processing order](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) of `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. Within a single query, the optimizer can and will push conversion operations past filters.